# D3 graph with area fill not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, grid, axis, area

I would like get the area in the line graph to fill correctly. (Look at the picture to see problem)

Notice the area filled and the text under the fill:

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">

.area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
    stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<svg width="860" height="400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeYear);

var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
    .tickSize(width);

var area = d3.area()
    .x0(function () {
    return 0,width;
})
    .x1(function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
}).y0(function () {
    return height,height;
})
    .y1(function (d) {
    return y(d.close);
});

var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(customXAxis);

g.append("g")
    .call(customYAxis);

function customXAxis(g) {
  g.call(xAxis);
  g.select(".domain").remove();
  g.selectAll(".tick line")
  .attr("stroke", "#e9e9e9")
  .attr("height","510px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -height + ")");
}

function customYAxis(g) {
  g.call(yAxis);
  g.select(".domain").remove();
  g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line").attr("stroke", "#e9e9e9");
  g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("x", width - 18).attr("dy", -4);
}

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);

g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

});

</script>
```

Also if possible, if anyone knows, how can you get the area fill to not overlap the y-axis text and all the axis-lines, so the text and the axis-lines gets on top of the area fill.

And also one more thing, I've been trying for hours. How to get x-axis lines to create a grid together with the grey y-axis lines?

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your primary question:

You are using a line generator to create an area graph - when filling the generated path, you simply connect the first and last points, hence your image. How does the generator "know" where the base of the filled area should be? A y axis value of zero may be common for the base, but it certainly isn't universal. *In any event, the line generator would need to include points with a scaled y value of 0 to create the proper fill - this would not be an accurate line representing the data unless the start and end points had y values of 0, this is why d3 provides an area generator in addition to the line generator.*

Instead of d3.line, use d3.area ([also, here's a canonical example likely using your data](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195)):

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); })   // top of area
    .y0(yScale(0));                           // bottom of area
```

the .y0 method is optional, if it isn't specified, it defaults to zero, but here's the documentation on it:

> If y is specified, sets the y0 accessor to the specified function or
>   number and returns this area generator. If y is not specified, returns
>   the current y0 accessor, which defaults to:
>
> `function y() {   return 0; }`
>
> When an area is generated, the y0 accessor will be invoked for each
>   defined element in the input data array, being passed the element d,
>   the index i, and the array data as three arguments. See area.x0 for
>   more information. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape)).

The y1 method represents the top of the graph (the same as the y accessor in your line graph), the y0 method represents the bottom, which in your case is constant.

Comment: @Martin Glad to help. As your question contains multiple questions, you could post other specific questions (if they remain unsolved) as new questions - this way answers will all focus on the same question and are ideally more useful to future users looking to solve a specific issue (though I'm sure the grid line question has been previously asked a few times, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766379/d3-adding-grid-to-simple-line-chart).